# How to use a RecyclerView within a LinearLayout when using fragments?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I get the follwoing error if I place my RecyclerView inside a LinearLayout along with a TextView, why is this? It works fine hen there is only a RecyclerView.

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Title ....."
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_beat_box_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment

```
public class SoundBoardFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "SoundBoardFragment";
private BeatBox mBeatBox;
private static final String ARG_FOLDER_NAME = "soundboard_folder";
private static String mFolderName;

public static SoundBoardFragment newInstance(String folderName)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "createFragment " + folderName);
    mFolderName = "sounds/" + folderName;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_FOLDER_NAME, folderName);
    SoundBoardFragment fragment = new SoundBoardFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate " + mFolderName);
    mBeatBox = new BeatBox(getActivity(),mFolderName);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beat_box, container,false);


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_beat_box_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SoundAdapter(mBeatBox.getSounds()));
    return recyclerView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mBeatBox.release();

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_sound_board, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_item_quit:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private class SoundHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Button mButton;
    private Sound mSound;

    public SoundHolder (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container)
    {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_sound, container, false));
        mButton = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_sound_button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bindSound(Sound sound)
    {
        mSound = sound;
        mButton.setText(mSound.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mBeatBox.play(mSound);
    }
}

private class SoundAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SoundHolder>{
    private List<Sound> mSounds;

    public SoundAdapter(List<Sound> sounds)
    {
        mSounds=sounds;
    }

    @Override
    public SoundHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        return new SoundHolder(inflater,parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SoundHolder holder, int position) {
        Sound sound = mSounds.get(position);
        holder.bindSound(sound);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSounds.size();
    }
}

}
```

Logcat results

```
03-25 21:56:05.258 25429-25429/com.example.blah.soundboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.blah.soundboard, PID: 25429
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.blah.soundboard/com.example.blah.soundboard.SoundBoardActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4309)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4059)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Each itemView is a Button inside a FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list_item_sound_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
tools:text="Sound name">
</Button>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show the logcat output?

Comment: Where does "itemView" comes from in SoundHolder (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) ?

Comment: itemView is the root view

Answer (score 3):

The `View` object you return in a fragment's `onCreateView` should be the view of the Fragment. So your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beat_box, container,false);


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_beat_box_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SoundAdapter(mBeatBox.getSounds()));
    return view;
}
```

After make that change it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your fragment `onCreateView` you return the `RecyclerView`. Instead you should return the variable named "view", which is the rootView of the layout.

What's happening is the `RecyclerView` is being attached in two places.